# Split class name

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```html
<section class="my-account-box-element box box-decoration-3 gutter-row-2">
    <div class="box-inner">
        <div class="box-content group">
            <div class="box-panel">
                <ul class="box-panel-nav stack-list">
                    <li class="gutter-col-4">
                        <span class="item icon-home icon-color-1">
                            <a class="link-color-1" href="/myaccount">Моята Сметка</a>
                        </span>
                    </li>
```

Hi, While finding the class name in the span which is "icon-color-1", I found that "icon-color-1" changes to "icon-color-0" according to the condition. Need to split the class name into two parts

Tried the following but not very useful:

```java
WebElement myAccountBoxElement = driver.findElement(By.className("my-account-box-element"));
WebElement spanItem = myAccountBoxElement.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
boolean itemColor = (spanItem.getAttribute("class").contains("item-color-1")) ? true : false;
```

Comment: So you mean after you get the class name of the span, you need to check if the class name ends with 1 or 0, is that right?

Comment: yes.Exactly. Need to do the substring of item-color-1. if get 0 then state-1 else state-2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used java for a while, but will give it a try and see how it works.

```java
// simplify the span locating
WebElement spanItem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".my-account-box-element span"));

int colorNum = -1;
String[] classNames = spanItem.getAttribute("class").split(" ");
for(String className : classNames) {
    // html says "icon-color-", your code says "item-color-"
    if(className.startsWith("icon-color-")) {
       colorNum = Integer.parseInt(className.replace("icon-color-", ""));
       break;
    }
}

if (colorNum == 0) {
    // do stuff for item-color-0 element
} else if (colorNum == 1) {
    // do stuff for item-color-1 element
} else {
    // exception
}
```

Comment: If you please let me know how to use "cssSelector" instead of xpaths.

Comment: @user2340124: A good css selector tutorial [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/). For selenium, the followings are useful enough: `#`, `.`, `>`, `+`, `:not`, `[foo="bar"]`, `[foo~="bar"]`, `[foo*="bar"]`, `[foo^="bar"]`, `[foo$="bar"]`

Answer (score 0):

Get class name through array and split it...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validations(){

        var inp_valid=/^[A-Z a-z]{4,}$/;
        var inpm_valid=/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{3}$/;
        var inpn_valid= /^\d{10}$/;

        var inp = document.querySelectorAll("input"); 
            for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) 
            {
                var inpslipt = inp[i].className.split(' ');

                    for (var j =0; j < inpslipt.length; j++) 
                    {
                        if(inpslipt[j] == "names")
                        {
                            if ( (inp[i].value == "") || !inp_valid.test(inp[i].value) ) 
                            {
                                inp[i].focus();
                                alert("please enter a valid name");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(inpslipt[j] == "mail")
                        {
                            if ( (inp[i].value == "") || !inpm_valid.test(inp[i].value) ) 
                            {
                                inp[i].focus();
                                alert("please enter a valid email");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(inpslipt[j] == "number")
                        {
                            if ( (inp[i].value == "") || !inpn_valid.test(inp[i].value) ) 
                            {
                                inp[i].focus();
                                alert("please enter a valid number");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            document.forms["myform"].submit();
    }
</script>
```